# Memoization giving less performance and taking more time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, optimization, memoization

I was solving project euler in freecodecamp. When solving problem no 14 i use recursion and tried to increase the performance using memorization. But without memoization it is taking less time to execute and with memoization it is taking more time. Is memoization implementation is correct? What is wrong with this code? Can any one explain?

```
//Memoized version of the longestCollatzSequence project euler
let t1 = Date.now();

// function recurseWrapper(n) {
//     let count = 0;
//     let memo = {}

//     function recurseCollatzSequence(n) {
//         if (n in memo) {
//             return memo[n];
//         } else {
//             if (n === 1) {
//                 return;
//             } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
//                 count++;
//                 memo[n / 2] = recurseCollatzSequence((n / 2))
//             } else {
//                 count++;
//                 memo[(3 * n) + 1] = recurseCollatzSequence(((3 * n) + 1))
//             }
//             return count
//         }

//     }
//     return recurseCollatzSequence(n);
// }

//Without memoization (better performance)

function recurseWrapper(n) {
    let count = 0;

    function recurseCollatzSequence(n) {

        if (n === 1) {
            return;
        } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
            count++;
            recurseCollatzSequence((n / 2))
        } else {
            count++;
            recurseCollatzSequence(((3 * n) + 1))
        }
        return count

    }
    return recurseCollatzSequence(n);
}


function longestCollatzSequence(n) {
    let max = 0;
    let startNum = 0;
    for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        let changeMax = recurseWrapper(i)
        if (changeMax > max) {
            max = changeMax;
            startNum = i;
        }
    }
    return startNum;
}

console.log(longestCollatzSequence(54512))
let t2 = Date.now() - t1;
console.log(`time taken by first instruction ${t2}`);
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(900000));
let t3 = Date.now() - t1 - t2
console.log(`time taken by second instruction ${t3}`);
let t4 = Date.now() - t1 - t2 - t3
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(1000000))
console.log(`time taken by third instruction ${t4}`);
```

Comment: There are other things going wrong but the main issue I see with memoization is that you're mixing up recursion and memo. I'm not entirely sure if that causes bugs because it's so hard to reason about the way you've written it here. The general rule of thumb should be: in `recurseCollatzSequence(n)` you only read `memo[n]` and write to `memo[n]`. Not to `memo[n / 2]` or `memo[(3*n)+1]`. So, remove both assignments to `memo` and add `memo[n] = count` just before `return count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my limited understanding of the collatz conjecture,  when starting at a number `n`, with all of the operations that you do, you should never see the same number again until you reach 1 (otherwise you would end up in an infinite loop). So your `memo` object will always hold unique keys that will never match the current number `n`, so `if (n in memo)` will never be true.

It actually seems that you want to memoize your results for further calls `recurseWrapper()` within your loop, so that you can prevent computing results you've already seen. At the moment you are not doing that, as you are creating a new `memo` object each time you call `recurseWrapper()`, removing all of the memoized values. You can instead return your inner auxiliary recursive wrapper function that closes over the `memo` object so that you keep the one memo object for all calls of the recursive wrapper function.

But even then we will still face issues, because of how the `count` is being calculated. For example, if you call `recurseWrapper(n)` and it takes 10 iterations to call `recurseCollatzSequence(k)`, the returned count of `recurseCollatzSequence(k)` is going to be `10` plus whatever number it takes to compute the Collatz sequence for `k`. If we memoize this number, we can face issues. If we again call  `recurseWrapper` on another number `m`, `recurseWrapper(m)`, and this time it takes 20 iterations to get to the same call of `recurseCollatzSequence(k)`, we will use our memoized value for `k`. But this value holds an additional count for the `10` that it took to get from `n` to `k`, and not just the count that it took to get from `k` to `1`. As a result, we need to change how you're computing `count` in your recursive function so that it is *pure*, so that calling a function with the same arguments always produces the same result.

As Vincent also points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558511/memoization-giving-less-performance-and-taking-more-time/72559011#comment128173285_72558511), you should be memoizing the current number, ie: `memo[n]` and not the number you're about to compute the Collatz count for (that memoization is done when you recurse):

```js
function createCollatzCounter() {
  const memo = {};
  return function recurseCollatzSequence(n) {
    if (n in memo) {
      return memo[n];
    } else {
      if (n === 1) {
        memo[n] = 0;
      } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
        memo[n] = 1 + recurseCollatzSequence(n / 2);
      } else {
        memo[n] = 1 + recurseCollatzSequence((3 * n) + 1);
      }
      return memo[n];
    }
  }
}

function longestCollatzSequence(n) {
  let max = 0;
  let startNum = 0;
  const recurseWrapper = createCollatzCounter();
  for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
    let changeMax = recurseWrapper(i)
    if (changeMax > max) {
      max = changeMax;
      startNum = i;
    }
  }
  return startNum;
}

console.time("First");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(54512));
console.timeEnd("First");
console.time("Second");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(900000));
console.timeEnd("Second");
console.time("Third");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(1000000));
console.timeEnd("Third");
```

In comparison, the below shows times without memo:

```js
//Without memoization (better performance)

function recurseWrapper(n) {
    let count = 0;

    function recurseCollatzSequence(n) {

        if (n === 1) {
            return;
        } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
            count++;
            recurseCollatzSequence((n / 2))
        } else {
            count++;
            recurseCollatzSequence(((3 * n) + 1))
        }
        return count

    }
    return recurseCollatzSequence(n);
}


function longestCollatzSequence(n) {
    let max = 0;
    let startNum = 0;
    for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        let changeMax = recurseWrapper(i)
        if (changeMax > max) {
            max = changeMax;
            startNum = i;
        }
    }
    return startNum;
}

console.time("First");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(54512))
console.timeEnd("First");
console.time("Second");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(900000));
console.timeEnd("Second");
console.time("Third");
console.log(longestCollatzSequence(1000000));
console.timeEnd("Third");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a streamlined version of the solution with minimal noise around memoization and recursion.

```
let memo = {};
function collatzSequence(n) {
    if (! (n in memo)) {
        if (n == 1) {
            memo[n] = 1;
        }
        else if ((n % 2) === 0) {
            memo[n] = 1 + collatzSequence(n/2);
        } else {
            memo[n] = 1 + collatzSequence(3*n + 1);
        }
    }
    return memo[n];
}

function longestCollatzSequence(n) {
    let max = 0;
    let startNum = 0;
    for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        let changeMax = collatzSequence(i)
        if (changeMax > max) {
            max = changeMax;
            startNum = i;
        }
    }
    return startNum;
}

console.log(longestCollatzSequence(14))
```

And if you're willing to accept a bit of golf, here is a shorter version still of the first function.

```
let memo = {1: 1};
function collatzSequence(n) {
    if (!(n in memo)) {
        memo[n] = 1 + collatzSequence(0 === n%2 ? n/2 : 3*n+1);
    }
    return memo[n];
}
```

The reason why this matters has to do with how we think.  As long as code reads naturally to us, how long it takes to write and think about it is directly correlated with how long it is.  (This has been found to be true across a variety of languages in many places.  I know that [Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605351) certainly has it.) Therefore learning to think more efficiently about code will make it faster for you to write.

And that is why learning how to use techniques without talking about the technique you're using makes you better at that technique.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time figuring out I found a working solution.
The code below improved time complexity. Thanks all for helping me.

```
//Memoized version of the longestCollatzSequence project euler
let memo = {}

function recurseWrapper(n) {
    let count = 0;
    if (n in memo) {
        return memo[n];
    } else {
        function recurseCollatzSequence(n) {
            if (n === 1) {
                return;
            } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
                count++;
                recurseCollatzSequence((n / 2))
            } else {
                count++;
                recurseCollatzSequence(((3 * n) + 1))
            }

            return count

        }
        let c = recurseCollatzSequence(n);
        memo[n] = c;
        return c;
    }

}

function longestCollatzSequence(n) {
    let max = 0;
    let startNum = 0;
    for (let i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        let changeMax = recurseWrapper(i)
        if (changeMax > max) {
            max = changeMax;
            startNum = i;
        }
    }
    return startNum;
}
longestCollatzSequence(14)
```

Comment: You are still doing less memoization than you think.  Once you enter `recurseCollatzSequence` you do not recursively check your `memo` and so STILL redo work.

Comment: Also `recurseWrapper` is completely unnecessary.  Just change the name of `recurseCollatzSequence` to `collatzSequence`, call it directly, and let the fact that it is recursive be an implementation detail.  The more naturally and directly you write recursion, the easier it will be for you to think well about it and apply it where needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a little more @btilly?? I am still confused.

Comment: I just added a solution that takes out the unnecessary noise.  If you compare it to your solution, you'll find that it runs significantly faster, and is significantly shorter.  The code pattern that I used is standard for handrolled memoization.